# Powershell Automation in ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell-2.0

We are trying to automate running of multiple powershell scripts in AWS EC2 instance.  Any suggestion how this can be done.  These execution has to be sequential.

Comment: This question is way too broad. Take a look at `winrm`, `Ansible` and `chef` (just to name a few)

Comment: or even user-data, cloud-init, salt, puppet, aws run-command.

Answer (score 0):

In order to configure state on a fresh EC2 instance, you can use 'User Data' in order to:

a. Fully provision and configure state using powershell, see:

[image]

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html#instancedata-add-user-data

b. Install an agent for a configuration management tool such as Puppet, Chef, Ansible (as mentioned in the comment above). An example of provisioning stock Window's AMI's can be followed here: http://blog.rolpdog.com/2015/09/manage-stock-windows-amis-with-ansible.html

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to trigger scripts on an existing Amazon EC2 instance (or a whole fleet of instances), also consider [Running PowerShell Commands or Scripts with Amazon EC2 Run Command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/remote-commands-psscript.html).